# Node.js - Sequelize.js nested association check in outer where condition - undefined

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js, where-clause, subquery

Implementation using Sequelize version: "^4.15.0"

I am trying to add a where condition from the 2 level down the associations included.

```
Model1.find({
    include: [
       {
           model: Model2,
           as: 'model2_alias',
           attributes: [
               'model2_id'
           ],
           include: [{
               model: Model3,
               as: 'model3_alias',
               attributes: [
                   'model3_id'
               ]
           }]
       }
    ],
    where: {
        model3_alias.id: { [Op.in]: [1, 2, 3] }
    }
});
```

I have tired the method:

```
where: {
    '$model2_alias.model3_alias.id$': { [Op.in]: [1, 2, 3] }
}
```

But is gives the error that `model2_alias.model3_alias.id` is undefined / not found.

The above does work when written as `'$model2_alias.id$': { [Op.in]: [1, 2, 3] }` so syntax must be write but how to go one more level down.

When executed the formed SQL statement in any MySQL management tool, gives proper result so the `where` conditions that I am trying to implement isn't wrong either.

Any ideas what am I missing here or this works for one level only. Then what to do for more levels?

Comment: You are using `model2_id` and `model3_id`, shouldn't it be just `id` ? Then `'$model2_alias.model3_alias.id$'` should work

Comment: I've been stuck on this matter for a while now. I cannot find *any* documentation on this . All examples I see are using only one level of nested column. Is that all that is possible? And yes, I know that I can put a where in each nested `include`, but I need to put it in the top level `where` block because that condition needs to be `or`'ed with other conditions in the top-level model.

Would appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 4):

You can add where at any level like this -

```
Model.find({
    where : { 
    // where 1
    },
    include : [{
        model : Model1,
        where : {
        // Where 2
        },
        include : [{
            model : Model2,
            where : {
            // Where 3
            }
        }]
    }]

});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, we can write the `where` condition with each `include` object but the SQL I need required the condition to be at the outer end. Anyways, I found that `sequelize` was creating a `sub query` which had the join and so the condition didn't work. Fixed it in other way.

Comment: I've been stuck on this matter for a while now. I cannot find *any* documentation on this . All examples I see are using only one level of nested column. Is that all that is possible? And yes, I know that I can put a where in each nested `include`, but I need to put it in the top level `where` block because that condition needs to be `or`'ed with other conditions in the top-level model.

Would appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can try

```
sequelize.where()
```

e.g.

```
sequelize.where(
      sequelize.literal('"model2_alias.model3_alias.id"'), { [Op.in]: [1, 2, 3] }
    )
```

About `sub query`, it means that you use `limit`/`offset` + (`1:m` relation or have `left join`).
If you have `1:1` relation, just add `required: true` to `include` and you'll get `inner join` instead of `left join` and `sequelize` don't create `sub query`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your code didn't work because you used `model1_id` instead of `id`. So the code should be

```
Model1.find({
    include: [
       {
           model: Model2,
           as: 'model2_alias',
           attributes: [
               'id'
           ],
           include: [{
               model: Model3,
               as: 'model3_alias',
               attributes: [
                   'id'
               ]
           }]
       }
    ],
    where: {
        '$model2_alias.model3_alias.id$': { [Op.in]: [1, 2, 3] }
    }
});
```

Also as @Rahul mentioned, you can use where directly inside your include as well

```
Model1.find({
    include: [
       {
           model: Model2,
           as: 'model2_alias',
           attributes: [
               'id'
           ],
           include: [{
               model: Model3,
               where: {
                  'id': { [Op.in]: [1, 2, 3] }
               }
               as: 'model3_alias',
               attributes: [
                   'id'
               ]
           }]
       }
    ],
});
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. But `model1_id` was just mentioned to differentiate that those are `id` column for respective `models`. Anyways, I found that `sequelize` was creating a `sub query` which had the join and so the condition didn't work. Fixed it in other way.